# Automatically login Active Directory users into Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, nginx, active-directory

I have a rails application running on nginx + unicorn and I want that users can login in with their Active Directory crendentials. I've already implemented connecting to AD server and authenticating users, but they need to enter passwords.

Is it possible to somehow get this information on this setup? I've found some topics about this problems, but they don't quite explain how to solve this problem and most of the answers are for IIS sever.

I know that it propably can work only in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Signing in automatically is handled by the web server, not your application. Since you are using nginx, there are a couple of third party modules you can use, such as [spnego-http-auth-nginx-module](https://github.com/stnoonan/spnego-http-auth-nginx-module) or [nginx-mod-auth-kerb](https://github.com/fintler/nginx-mod-auth-kerb). IIS has support built-in, of course.

Once you've set up the web server, your application can retrieve the user's username from the REMOTE_USER environment variable. Internet Explorer will automatically log in; Firefox and Chrome will do so if they have been configured for the domain by the system administrator, but this is off by default.